# Why doesn't useEffect hook work as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I've never used hooks in React and I'm trying to use `useEffect()` but I don't seem to get the basics of its correct structure and use.

I was able to achieve the results with plain JavaScript but with `useState` the state remains untouched.

Then I found `useEffect` after searching for a while, and this is what I could get it to look like-

```
// Background Parallax Effect

let [translateY,setTranslateY] = useState(0);
useEffect(()=> {
    const getScrollPos = ()=> {
        setTranslateY(window.scrollY*(-.2));

        requestAnimationFrame(getScrollPos);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",getScrollPos)
},[translateY]);
```

I highly suspect that its structure isn't as it is supposed to be.

So I want to know the fixes and *how it exactly works* to help understand the structure better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your first code is that you add `translateY` as a dependency to useEffect. . You should remove translateY as a dependency and also remove the event listener when the component unmounts. Also you have a `requestAnimationCallback` within the getScrollPos function which is triggered unconditionally causing infinite loop

```
useEffect(()=> {
    const getScrollPos = ()=> {
        setTranslateY(window.scrollY*(-.2));
    }
    const setScrollPos = () => {
       requestAnimationFrame(getScrollPos);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",setScrollPos);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",setScrollPos)
    }
},[]);
```

Note that if you update the state with same value, react prevents a re-render.

In the second code, although you call the state update by using `listenScroll` directly in render function, it doesn't cause a loop because you would be setting the same value to update state and hence an infinite loop doesn't occur

Comment: There was some logical error in my rest of the code that I've fixed now. Thanks for your help!